# Plot PieChart as a line (or as a stacked BarChart)

Tags: charts

How to plot relative proportions on a line? IE PieChart as stacked BarChart that is normalised.

For example,

```
diversityCoearse = {"Firmicutes" -> 1000, 
  "Bacteroidetes" -> 200, "Verrucomicrobia" -> 20,
  "Proteobacteria" -> 40, "Actinobacteria" -> 32 };

PieChart[diversityCoearse[[All, 2]],
 SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1},
 ChartLabels -> Placed[{Style[#, 13] &/@ diversityCoearse[[All, 1]]}, {"RadialCallout"}],
 PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: PieChart example]

And I would like to have:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
diversityCoearse = 
  Association[
   "Firmicutes" -> 1000, "Bacteroidetes" -> 200, "Verrucomicrobia" -> 20, 
   "Proteobacteria" -> 40, "Actinobacteria" -> 32]

BarChart[diversityCoearse,
 ImageSize -> Large,
 AspectRatio -> 1/6,
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ChartLabels -> 
   Placed[Keys @ diversityCoearse, {{.5, 1}, {0, 0}}, Rotate[#, 45 °] &]]
```

[image: bar_chart]

Comment: Works wonderfully, especially after adding @kglr trick: ```Normalize[diversityCoearse, Total]```

Answer (score 10):

```
 RectangleChart[Callout[{#2, 1}, #]] & @@@ diversityCoearse, 
  ChartStyle -> 97,  AspectRatio -> 1/2, BarSpacing->{0,0}, Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** using `Normalize`d  data:

```
diversityC = diversityCoearse;
diversityC[[All,2]]=Normalize[diversityC[[All,2]], Total];

RectangleChart[Callout[{#2, 1}, #] & @@@   diversityC, ChartStyle -> 97, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, Axes -> {True, False}, BarSpacing -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

To start you off:

```
Graphics[Riffle[ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length[dc]], 
                MapThread[Tooltip,
                          {Rectangle[{#1, 0}, {#2, 1/8}] & @@@ 
                           Partition[FoldList[Plus, 0, Normalize[Values[diversityCoearse],
                                                                 Total]], 2, 1],
                           Keys[diversityCoearse]}]],
         Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}]
```

[image: chart]